# Display a list of users that are nearby using UID and on clicking dsplay their profile

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to display a user that is using my app, using UID?

I am getting all the UIDs from Firebase.

I want users to be able to view each other's profiles if they are near to each other.

can we use google nearby places to do this? If so how?
Any kind of insight would be great!!
thanks

Comment: Are y ou using Firestore or the Realtime Database?

Comment: real time database

Answer (score 0):

> I want users to be able to view each other's profiles if they are near to each other.

Since you're using the Realtime Database (according to your last comment), to display some users that are nearby, you need to use a library that does that. Unfortunately, the Realtime Database doesn't currently have the capability to do that. So for Android, you should consider using [GeoFire](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/geofire-android/) to display the users within a given geographic area.

Comment: could you please guide me on how i should do this.
I am completely blank, by doing literally days of research.

I have researched wifi direct, google nearby places, geofencing, geolocation, geofire, Bluetooth address, etc.

Im quite new to coding so this is making it hard to understand, if i could get a simple explanation on how to do this would be awesome.

Comment: It's a bit too broad to reasonably write an answer, here on Stackoverflow. So you should give it again a try, and if you get stuck in a certain step, please post a new question here, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Hey Aaron. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: i have started to code.
im starting with the recycler view to display users, not yet finished this.
once im done with recycler view.

i will start with the geofire , query and stuff.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX7WxAZAXC0
i am refering this video to get a rough idea on how to do it.

i dont know at the moment how it will work.
But if i face any issues or doubts, i will ask for help over here.

Comment: I hope i can do this.

if i cant, i might end up displaying all users in the recycler view, that are using the app.

Comment: You should give it a try. It should work for sure. However, if get stuck, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?